# Convert mobile gesture to mouse input?

Tags: unity

I use `Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x` on a mobile device and do something like this:

```
transform.Rotate(-Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x / 10 , 0,0);
```

But now I'm switching to a Windows platform.

How can I convert `Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x` to `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` & then drag left and right?

ok i test this , it's work well, but it reset the difference rotation angle when click

````
private Vector3 _prevPos;

Vector2 ret = Input.mousePosition - _prevPos;
_prevPos = Input.mousePosition;

then 

transform.Rotate(ret.x / 10 , 0,0);
```
````

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't provide readers much information. You could improve this post by editing it to include information about *how* your attempted solution didn't work. For example: what result did you get & what result did you expect?

Comment: If this code solved your problem, then you should post it as an Answer below, not edit it into the question. If it does not solve the problem, then you should explain how it differs from what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used this method:

```
private Vector3 _prevPos;

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        _prevPos = Input.mousePosition
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        ret = Input.mousePosition - _prevPos;
        _prevPos = Input.mousePosition;

        transform.Rotate(ret.y / 10, 0, ret.x );
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this method deviate from what you would call "perfect"? We can only help you fix the remaining issues if you tell us what they are.

Comment: If you want to get the mouse movement since the last frame, you can use `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` and `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")`